# How do i pass nested models objects to the parent in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I was trying to put values into my different models and when i use toJson() function of the parent model, it suppose to call other models with their objects and form a json that i can send to firebase.

Below is the model

```
class Customer {
  String name;
  String avatar;
  String customerId;
  List<Receivers> receivers;

  Customer({this.name = 'my name', this.avatar ='image-link', this.customerId ='123455', this.receivers});

  Customer.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    name = json['name'];
    avatar = json['avatar'];
    customerId = json['customerId'];
    if (json['receivers'] != null) {
      receivers = new List<Receivers>();
      json['receivers'].forEach((v) {
        receivers.add(new Receivers.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    print('i was called 1');
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['avatar'] = this.avatar;
    data['customerId'] = this.customerId;
    if (this.receivers != null) {
      print('i was called 2');
      data['receivers'] = this.receivers.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Receivers {
  String adddress;
  String apartmentNumber;
  String apartmentType;
  DropoffCoordinates dropoffCoordinates;
  String name;
  int phoneNumber;

  Receivers(
      {this.adddress = 'worldwide',
      this.apartmentNumber = 'no1',
      this.apartmentType = 'flat',
      this.dropoffCoordinates,
      this.name = 'my name',
      this.phoneNumber = 89084884});

  Receivers.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    adddress = json['adddress'];
    apartmentNumber = json['apartmentNumber'];
    apartmentType = json['apartmentType'];
    dropoffCoordinates = json['dropoffCoordinates'] != null
        ? new DropoffCoordinates.fromJson(json['dropoffCoordinates'])
        : null;
    name = json['name'];
    phoneNumber = json['phoneNumber'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    print('i was called 2');
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['adddress'] = this.adddress;
    data['apartmentNumber'] = this.apartmentNumber;
    data['apartmentType'] = this.apartmentType;
    if (this.dropoffCoordinates != null) {
      print('i was called 3');
      data['dropoffCoordinates'] = this.dropoffCoordinates.toJson();
    }
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['phoneNumber'] = this.phoneNumber;
    return data;
  }
}

class DropoffCoordinates {
  double latitude;
  double longitude;

  DropoffCoordinates({this.latitude = 1.3566, this.longitude = 2.47655});

  DropoffCoordinates.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    latitude = json['latitude'];
    longitude = json['longitude'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    print('i was called 4');
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['latitude'] = this.latitude;
    data['longitude'] = this.longitude;
    return data;
  }
}
```

I hardcoded the values, to just see the results of the various toJson() function that is been called, but the problem now is:

**The nested models are not been called or show in the result of the print toJson() fucntion**

Below is the value i get from the print result

```
print('CUSTOMER MODEL: ${customerInstance.toJson()}');
print('RECEIVERS MODEL: ${receiversInstance.toJson()}');
print('DROPOFFPOINTS MODEL: ${dropoffCordinstance.toJson()}');
```

**RESULT ON CONSOLE**

```
D/ViewRootImpl@4ab0077[MainActivity](21376): ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@4ab0077[MainActivity](21376): ViewPostIme pointer 1
Reloaded 38 of 1370 libraries in 6,641ms.
I/flutter (21376): i was called 1
I/flutter (21376): CUSTOMER MODEL: {name: my name, avatar: image-link, customerId: 123455}
I/flutter (21376): i was called 2
I/flutter (21376): RECEIVERS MODEL: {adddress: worldwide, apartmentNumber: no1, apartmentType: flat, name: my name, phoneNumber: 89084884}
I/flutter (21376): i was called 4
I/flutter (21376): DROPOFFPOINTS MODEL: {latitude: 1.3566, longitude: 2.47655}
```

Please help, i just need to get values from the nested model to the Customer Model, so i can send to firestore in a map form using it's toJson() function.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Without the possibility to see the code that instance your `Customer` object it is very difficult to understand what is wrong. There are also some error in you model classed.

My advice is to:

1. Generate a complete JSON
2. Generate dart classed using [quicktype.io](https://app.quicktype.io)

3. Generate a new `Customer` model and fill all the child properties/objects
4. Once you have your complete `Customer` object print it using `toJson()` function or the method you prefer

Comment: i just did what you asked, thanks for the response.

this is the link to the file
https://app.quicktype.io?share=79d1qgHAOqk6RrjsNbl3

I will like to ask, for instance:  my current latitude and longitude was send to the ```DropoffCoordinates Model class``` object, now i filled a form which populate the ```Receiver model class```.

Comment: Why if i call 

```Customer customerInstance;```





```print('Customer Model: ${customerInstance.toJson()});```



it brings out only the objects that is already in the model, it does not call toJson() of the nested models.


**I/flutter (21376): CUSTOMER MODEL: {name: isaac, avatar: image-link, customerId: 123455}**

Comment: Have you tried to use the helper generated by quicktype.io? `customerToJson(customerInstance)`?